# Swift blur effect is not dismissed when returning to main view

Tags: ios, swift, uiblureffect

I want to show a subview, which is transperrent, therefore blur the main view controller. This works fine, but when returning to the main view controller, the blur stays - and it doesn't go to any section in the main view, like view did appear or popoverPresentationControllerDidDismissPopover.

I run this code to create the blur and show the subview:

```
if !UIAccessibilityIsReduceTransparencyEnabled() {
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

    let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.extraLight)
    let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
    blurEffectView.frame = self.view.bounds
    blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

    self.view.addSubview(blurEffectView)
}

let popOverVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PriceAlarmPopUp") as!  PriceAlarmPopupViewController
self.addChildViewController(popOverVC)
popOverVC.view.frame = self.view.frame
self.view.addSubview(popOverVC.view)

popOverVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

When finishing the subview, I do:

```
self.view.removeFromSuperview()
```

Is there anything I do wrong? I tried already several solutions, but was not able to get rid of the blur subview.

Comment: instead of removing the view controller main view i.e., self.view remove blurEffectView.removeFromSuperview()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep weak reference for your blur view, and later remove it from superview:

```
class MyVC: UIViewController {

    private weak var blurView: UIView?

    func foo() {
        if !UIAccessibilityIsReduceTransparencyEnabled() {
            self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.extraLight)
            let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
            blurEffectView.frame = self.view.bounds
            blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
            self.view.addSubview(blurEffectView)
            blurView = blurEffectView // HERE YOU SAVE WEAK REFERENCE
        }

        let popOverVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PriceAlarmPopUp") as!  PriceAlarmPopupViewController
        self.addChildViewController(popOverVC)
        popOverVC.view.frame = self.view.frame
        self.view.addSubview(popOverVC.view)

        popOverVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    }

    func fooDone() {
        blurView?.removeFromSuperview() // Blur view will be removed from sureview and automatically `blurView` becomes to `nil`
    }
}
```

If you want to hide it from another view controller, use closures:

```
class MyVC: UIViewController {
    func foo() {
        let popOverVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PriceAlarmPopUp") as!  PriceAlarmPopupViewController
        self.addChildViewController(popOverVC)
        popOverVC.view.frame = self.view.frame
        if !UIAccessibilityIsReduceTransparencyEnabled() {
            self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.extraLight)
            let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
            blurEffectView.frame = self.view.bounds
            blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
            self.view.addSubview(blurEffectView)
            popOverVC.userTappedCloseButtonClosure = { [weak blurEffectView] in
                blurEffectView?.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        }
        self.view.addSubview(popOverVC.view)
        popOverVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    }
}

class PriceAlarmPopupViewController: UIViewController {
    public var userTappedCloseButtonClosure: (() -> Void)?

    @IBAction func closeButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
        userTappedCloseButtonClosure?()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried that, and ran the fooDone function in my popOverVC when removing him. According to debugger, it enters the fooDone section, but still the blur is not dismissed :(

Comment: @AlexanderKo did you run `fooDone` in main thread? And check if `blurView` is `nil` before `removeFromSuperview()` was called.

Comment: I tried in my PopupView: :@IBAction func CloseButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
        self.view.removeFromSuperview()
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let vc = KeepaDataViewController()
            vc.fooDone()
        }
        
    } -> but unfortunately same result

Comment: @AlexanderKo Wait, so `CloseButtonAction(:)` is inside `PriceAlarmPopupViewController` right?

Comment: exactly. This is the popup view controller I open as popOverVC. There I want to press the close button, and close the popupviewcontroller and dismiss the blur.

Comment: Can it be that now the popupView is below the blurview?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149151/discussion-between-vasilii-muravev-and-alexander-ko).

Answer (score 1):

When the popup is dismissed, you have to remove the blur view, not `self.view`, i.e. `blurEffectView.removeFromSuperview()`.

Comment: But where can I run this code? I guess in the main view controller? But it doesn't jumps to any section in the code after running removeFromSuperView in the PopupViewController.

Comment: Put it in the base view controller's `viewWillAppear()`.

Answer (score 1):

Set your blur effect to nil. It's even animatable if you wish (in fact the only proper way to animate out of a blurview)

```
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.95, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseIn, animations:  {() -> Void in
        self.blurView.effect = nil
        }, completion: {(finished:Bool) -> Void in       
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Add tag to your view as shown bellow

```
let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.extraLight)
    let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
        blurEffectView.tag = 100

    blurEffectView.frame = self.view.bounds
    blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

    self.view.addSubview(blurEffectView)
```

Remove  blurEffectView view with tag

```
self.view.viewWithTag(100)?.removeFromSuperview()
```

Comment: Tried that, but unfortunately, with no positiv result...i have the feeling that something is not running like it should. thanks for your kind help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use protocols to solve this. I hope the example below helps.

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController, RemoveBlurViewDelegate {

//MARK: - Properties
private weak var blurView: UIView?

// MARK: - Navigation

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    
    if segue.identifier == "SegueToPopverVc" {
        
        if let popOver = segue.destination.contents as? PriceAlarmPopupViewController {
            
            popOver.removeBlurDelegate = self
            
            // Adds the bluer Effect
            let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .extraLight)
            let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
            blurEffectView.frame = self.view.bounds
            blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
            self.view.addSubview(blurEffectView)
            blurView = blurEffectView
        }
    }
}


//MARK: - Implentation of the RemoveBlurViewDelegate

func removeBluer() {
    blurView?.removeFromSuperview()
}

//MARK: - End of MAinViewController

}




//MARK: - Protocol to remove the blur from other VC

protocol RemoveBlurViewDelegate {
         func removeBluer()
  }

//MARK: - End of RemoveBlurViewDelegate protocol


//MARK: - PopupViewController
class PriceAlarmPopupViewController: UIViewController {


//MARK: - properties
var removeBlurDelegate: RemoveBlurViewDelegate?

//MARK: - PopupVieController life cycle

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    removeBlurDelegate?.removeBluer()
}

//MARK: - End of PriceAlarmPopupViewController

}
```